# Grails: How do I create filter like the ones in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, list, grails, filter

I want to sort the elements in my list and have the option of filter them the same way MS Excel does.

So it should be able to keep the filtered elements in the table and apply a filter within those results as well. Also be able to sort them without refreshing the whole table.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a criteria in you list action of your controller

```
def result

if ( params?.filter && params?.filterVal) {
    result = Book.createCriteria().list(max: params?.max, offset: params?.offset) {
         eq(params?.filter,params?.filterVal)
    }
} else {
    // normal list retrieval code
}
```

where `params?.filter` is the property to filter on and `params?.filterVal` is the value

Comment: and it'll save other (old) filters?

Comment: @fgualda87 can't really answer that question based on the fact there is no code here? I have no idea how you have implemented anything. I am just suggesting how you can code a controller action to respond to a filter based on a property and a value